# SQL search a tables twice within one statement: I get an error - Unknown column 'statut_comments.id_client' in 'on clause'

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

Can someone help me with this SQL please, cause I see error message as unknown column where I know the column are there?

```
SELECT 
   statut.*, 
   clien_1.Id, clien_1.mail, clien_1.nom, clien_1.prenom, 
   image_profil_1.image, 
   statut_comments.*, 
   clien_2.Id, clien_2.mail, clien_2.nom, clien_2.prenom, 
   image_profil_2.image  
FROM  
    statut
INNER JOIN 
    clien AS clien_1 ON statut.client_from = clien_1.Id
INNER JOIN  
    clien AS clien_2 ON statut_comments.id_client = clien_2.Id
INNER JOIN  
    statut_comments ON statut_comments.comment_id = statut.id
INNER JOIN 
    image_profil AS image_profil_1 ON image_profil_1.mail = clien_1.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    image_profil AS  image_profil_2 ON image_profil_2.mail = clients_2.Id
```

Comment: Without knowing the structures of the tables it is difficult to help. Are you sure the `blog_statut_comments` table has a `id_client` column?

Comment: Thanks @Oded. yeah sure. a part from the aliases every column are the same. What do  you thing about the structuring?

Comment: The error is accurate - are you certain you didn't misspell something (`client_id` instead of `id_client`, for example)? Perhaps the DB tables are set to be case sensitive?

Comment: It is better to post updates in the question body instead of comments.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is in my statements but I can't see where. Thanks for your help @Oded. I am new here that's why! How do get that code well formated here?

Answer (score 2):

THe problem is the order of your inner joins - you're using blog_statut_comments before you've joined to it.

Try changing the order of the joins.

Comment: Thank you @FionaT! I worked!Can I delete this since I am showing my data base for real?

Comment: I've removed the detail of the sql.

Comment: Thanks I changed the name of tables in case some one would try hack my data then it would take some more difficulties

Answer (score 0):

As Fiona already pointed out - you're referring to `statut_comments` before it's been added to the list of joined tables. Not sure if I "got this" - here's a visual explanation:

[image]

You basically need to change the order of your `JOINs`:

```
SELECT 
   (your list of columns)
FROM  
    statut
INNER JOIN     -- include the "status_comments" *BEFORE* refering to it!
    statut_comments ON statut_comments.comment_id = statut.id
INNER JOIN 
    clien AS clien_1 ON statut.client_from = clien_1.Id
INNER JOIN  
    clien AS clien_2 ON statut_comments.id_client = clien_2.Id
INNER JOIN 
    image_profil AS image_profil_1 ON image_profil_1.mail = clien_1.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    image_profil AS  image_profil_2 ON image_profil_2.mail = clients_2.Id
```

Comment: @Fiona Can someone help me with this queue to shows all available statut and their comments regardless whether the statut has a comment or not? I have tried 'LEFT/RIGHT JOIN' but it still gives me 'statut's which have 'statut_comments's .Thank you.